# Why am I getting errors running the coffee command in cygwin?

Tags: windows, node.js, intellij-idea, coffeescript, cygwin

I followed the [CoffeeScript installation guide](http://coffeescript.org/#installation) by installing Node.js with the `node-v0.10.9-x64.msi` installer.  I then started up a cygwin console and `cd`'d into the directory with my `.coffee` file.  If I type `coffee` all by itself, it gives me this error:

```
$ coffee
coffee>
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ENOTCONN
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at Socket._read (net.js:389:21)
    at Socket.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at Socket.read (net.js:291:43)
    at new Socket (net.js:185:10)
    at process.stdin (node.js:660:19)
    at new REPLServer (repl.js:132:15)
    at Object.exports.start (repl.js:312:14)
    at Object.module.exports.start (C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\repl.js:106:23)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:77:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\coffee:7:41)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

And if I run the command with `-lw` it gives me this error:

```
$ coffee -lw Example.js.coffee
Error: This socket is closed.
    at Socket._write (net.js:618:19)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:596:40)
    at lint (C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:468:15)
    at compileScript (C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:193:18)
    at C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:144:18
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

And if I run with just the `-l` option it gives me this error:

```
$ coffee -l Example.coffee
Error: This socket is closed.
    at Socket._write (net.js:618:19)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:596:40)
    at lint (C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:468:15)
    at compileScript (C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:193:18)
    at C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:144:18
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

But it seems like I can compile and/or watch option without the lint option and things work as expected.

I don't know anything about Node.js.  I've tried googling these errors and I see similar ones related to ports in use and socket issues.  I think it might be useful to note that I'm using Intellij IDEA (an IDE) and it has a CoffeeScript plugin which perhaps is interfering.  But when I turn Intellij off I still get these same errors so that might be a red herring.

Also, perhaps there's a specific cygwin version of node.js I should have installed instead of the one I got from the installation instructions?

If I type `node` all by itself, it says this:

```
$ node

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ENOTCONN
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at Socket._read (net.js:389:21)
    at Socket.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at Socket.read (net.js:291:43)
    at new Socket (net.js:185:10)
    at process.stdin (node.js:660:19)
    at startup (node.js:145:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Comment: Does it give the same errors without cygwin ?

Comment: @user568109 Yes, it does.

Comment: What happens if you type `node` by itself ?

Comment: @user568109 see the bottom of my edit

Comment: Your node installation looks broken. Could be a bug in the 0.10.9 version. Try re installing it and if it still gives error file an issue here - https://github.com/joyent/node/issues

Comment: @user568109 ok, thanks for your help.  I reinstalled and installed a different version and still got this error.  I opened an issue here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5618

Comment: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/176 looks related. Seems to be cygwin-specific

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [node no longer supports Cygwin](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation#building-on-cygwin).

One workaround is to use some variety of MSysGit as a console instead of Cygwin, at least for running node/coffeescript.  Git Bash supplies a good one.  You can get it [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads).